# How do I write "but if" in Chinese?

Tags: grammar

How can I express that something happens if another condition is true? (Eng: "Subject ... but if ... subject ...")

Example:

> I usually get up at six o'clock, **but if** I'm really tired, I sleep until eight.
>
> 我常起來六點，但是很累到八點睡覺。　（Can I write this?)

Comment: I think 不过如果 is better in this case

Comment: unless  ... in which case ...  除非。。。在这种情况下。。。

Comment: “但如果……的话”：我一般六点起床，但如果太累了的话，也可能一直睡到八点。

Answer (score 6):

A literal translation to "但要是" is fine here.

> I usually get up at six o'clock, but if I'm really tired, I sleep until eight.
>
> 我一般六点起床，但要是很累，我会睡到八点。

Comment: Thanks! So the first 是 goes away? It's never 但是要是 or 可是要是?

Comment: Not exactly never ... but seldom, because it looks a bit too verbose.

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver P.S. 到八点睡觉 means "go to bed/sleep at eight". To express "until" you need to use the structure here.

Comment: “但要是” is usually used in oral as well as “可要是”. “要是”=“要说”（to say）in this case.

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to say this. Literal translations of "but if" works fine. That is, any combination of "but":

- 可是
- 但是
- 但
- 不過

Followed by "if":

- 如果
- 要是

> 我通常六點起床，**但如果**很累會睡到八點。

Although that's sufficient, a construction using the ["的話"](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%9A%84%E8%A9%B1) conditional particle sounds perhaps somewhat more natural to me. That is, you can use any of the but / but if options above, followed by your condition (being tired), and then 的話. For example:

> 我通常六點起床，**但**很累**的話**會睡到八點。

Note that with the particle, a separate "if" after the "but" is not necessary, but can be used nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Just translate it word by word.

但 要是/但 如果/但 假如/不过 要是/不过 如果/etc. are all correct.

You can use 但是 or 但 as you like， both are correct. It just depend on how many syllables you want to say.